# react-pdf package not working in MeteorJs

Tags: reactjs, meteor, import, react-pdf

I created a test app in React using React PDF and its working but when I transfered it in Meteor the File wont load in Document. This is what I did

```
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";

// In my render method
<Document file="/sample.pdf">
    <Page pageNumber={1}/>
</Document>
```

I tried importing it like this

> import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack";

but It thorws an error and it wants me to install the following but i cant install it

> meteor npm install --save file-loader!pdfjs-dist